# Mega Tuning Mod Not Working

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I got the mega tuning DLC in ETS2. I have made sure it is downloaded, and I restarted the game multiple times. The customizations will simply not show up in the truck upgrade shop. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: Is mega tuning DLC, or a mod?

Comment: @Frank It is an official DLC that is bought on the Steam store for ETS2.            http://store.steampowered.com/app/461244/

Comment: You are driving a Scania truck, right?

Comment: Yes. I own a Scania

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on ETS2 in the steam application, click on "Properties".
2. Go to the "DLC" tab and make sure the "Install" checkbox on the DLC.

[image]